# How to specify the bind IP in Net::Telnet

Tags: perl, telnet

So I am stuck on this on, below I have some code that takes a local ip address as its bind address, then telnets to a specified server on a specified port and returns the value, the thing is I need it to bind to different IP addresses on a loop that are on the server and I cant figure out how to do that part.

**localhost => $ip**

I specified that below but when I run this it gets

**bad named parameter "localhost" given to Net::Telnet::new()**

Thanks in advance if anyone can tell what I did wrong here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $iplist = '/vbin/iplist';
use Net::Telnet;
for(0..50)
{
 my $remoteserver = shift;
 my $interface='eth2:'.$_;
 my $ip = `ifconfig  $interface|grep inet| cut -d':' -f2|awk '{print \$1}'`;
 chomp($ip,$interface);
 my $return = testport2("$ip","25");
 print "$ip:\t$return\n";
 print "$ip:\t$return\n";

}
sub testport2
{
 my $ip =shift;
 my $port = shift;
 my $mailserver = shift;
 my $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10, Port=>$port, Errmode => 'return', localhost => $ip );
 $telnet->open("$remoteserver");
 if ($telnet->errmsg)
 {
   return "errmsg: " . $telnet->errmsg . "\n";
 }else{
   return"success\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm#METHODS), `localhost` is a method, not a parameter:

```
my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new( Timeout=>10, Port=>$port, Errmode => 'return');
$telnet->localhost($ip);
$telnet->open($remoteserver);
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Unfortunately I got another error though.

**Can't locate object method "localhost" via package "Net::Telnet"**

Comment: What version are you using? Going from the [ChangeLog](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JROGERS/Net-Telnet-3.04/ChangeLog), this feature requires 3.04. `perl -MNet::Telnet -e 'print "$Net::Telnet::VERSION\n"'`

Comment: Yep it was the version, hopefully I can take it from here thanks alot.

Comment: Hey I ran into another issue, How can i return stdout, the server lets me connect but closes it with a message that I need to capture.